# How to use bootstrap date picker to get correct date format on your application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a small problem i am using Boostrap DatePicker, the problem is the format of the date on input-daterange. eg. 01/08/2020. It should read the following format and to be understood by the user well. e.g 09/01/2020. Below is my logic for using Bootstrap DatePicker, i am open to better approach to use date from start to end date.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
 <!---DatePicker for startDate and endDate.
   ----> 
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div class = "col-xl-10.5 col-lg-10.5 col-md-10 col-sm-10.5 col-10.5">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div><br>
  // date functionality
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
   $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
     autoclose:true,
     minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
     maxDate:new Date(year, 11, 31)

   });
 });
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

Comment: sorry is not clear what is the question, can you provide more context of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [format](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) option instead of `dateFormat`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
   $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
     format: "dd-mm-yy",
     autoclose:true,
     minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
     maxDate:new Date(year, 11, 31)
   });
 });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
   $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
     format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
     autoclose:true,
     minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
     maxDate:new Date(year, 11, 31)
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
 <!---DatePicker for startDate and endDate.
   ----> 
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div class = "col-xl-10.5 col-lg-10.5 col-md-10 col-sm-10.5 col-10.5">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div><br>
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks Amal, the issue was indeed on replacing the DateFormat to format:dd-mm-yyyy only. What a hustle mates lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. for your further reference visit [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is on the form control itself.e.g 01/08/2020. I want it to show this format 09/01/2020. Hope i making a sense here

Comment: I got your point. date format can be change. check this (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: it does not show the libraries for this date picker, i might be using incorrect library, i am getting scewed form control now.

Comment: Can i see the exact output that you are getting now ? if it's possible

Comment: <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div class = "col-xl-10.5 col-lg-10.5 col-md-10 col-sm-10.5 col-10.5">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   <input type="text" class=" form-control"  placeholder="enddate"/>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div><br/>
  <br/>

Comment: Change your input type as `date` and see

Comment: i did but the format its still incorrect, as it reads 'yy-mm-dd' and yet my input still scewed.

Comment: Check this (http://form.guide/html5/html-input-type-date-format.html)

Comment: I am not moving forward here, any alternatives mates please thanks.